# Administration Report - Microstrategy

Tags: admin, microstrategy

I am just beginning in microstrategy and have created few reports. I need a help here. I have created 10 reports say A B C D ....etc. I have got 5 end users. I want to know how many end users have have accessed these reports .Also there are some intelligence cubes and I want to know how many end users have created reports on their own.

I want to build as a report with these data. Where do I find these information?

Any guidance will be useful. I am using `MST 9.4.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistics you are looking for are collected by the [MicroStrategy Enterprise Manager](http://www.microstrategy.com/us/software/products/enterprise-manager).

Enterprise Manager is made of two components:

- An ETL process that loads usage data in his own data warehouse
- A MicroStrategy project with several precooked reports to analyze the data collected.

Comment: Thanks, Will take a look at this. I am just thinking, if the statistics  are getting stored in some tables and I want to create some report around this.

Comment: Not sure about that, you can use the Diagnostics and Performance Logging tool to log more or less the same information collected by Enterprise Manager, but then you will have these information in log files and you have to read and process them. Also extensive logging can be resource consuming and you don't want that on a production machine. If you need those details in a table, Enterprise Manager is the easiest way to achieve it.